# Открыть текстовый редактор в psql

Tags: postgresql, psql, работа-с-текстом

*GNU Readline* позволяет редактировать команду в редакторе,
указанном в `$EDITOR`, через последовательность
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>.
Но в `psql` это сочетание не работает.

Как отредактировать команду в своём редакторе?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте команду `\e`.
[Документация](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/app-psql.html):

> ```
> \e or \edit [ filename ] [ line_number ]
>
>     (…) If no filename is given, the current query buffer is copied to a
>     temporary file which is then edited in the same fashion. Or, if the
>     current query buffer is empty, the most recently executed query is
>     copied to a temporary file and edited in the same fashion.
> ```